# SQL Server query about updating column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have asked a similar question previously, but posting a new one as I do not want to confuse other
members, and there is an additional column.

What I am looking for is to update the column `ItemActual`. This needs to be updated with the difference with `ItemValue` for the latest `CurrentTime` for the same `StartTime` if any.

If there is no other entry for the same `StartTime` other than the current row, it needs to be the `ItemValue` itself. The comparisons are only to be done for items with the same name.

For eg, Rownum 283, `ItemActual = 347013` (since there is no other row with same `StartTime`).
This applies to row 235 as well, i.e. `ItemActual = 1086054.00`

For row 190, this needs to be `664031.00 - 533023.00 (comparing with row 145) = 131008`
But for row 10, this will be `532023.00`, since there is no earlier entry of same item with same `StartTime`.

```
Rownum  Name  ItemValue      CurrentTime        StartTime
 283    ABC     347013.00     3/05/2012 16:01   29/04/2012 6:29
 235    ABC    1086054.00    26/03/2012 14:05    7/03/2012 21:18
 190    ABC     664031.00    13/02/2012 13:42   29/01/2012 6:39
 145    ABC     533023.00     7/02/2012 14:01   29/01/2012 6:39
 100    ABC     532023.00     7/02/2012 13:33   29/01/2012 6:39
  55    ABC     532023.00     7/02/2012 12:52   29/01/2012 6:39
  10    ABC     532023.00     7/02/2012 12:51   29/01/2012 6:39
 310    DEF     351012.00     3/05/2012 16:01   29/04/2012 6:29
 261    DEF    1339066.00    26/03/2012 14:05    7/03/2012 21:18
 215    DEF     785034.00    13/02/2012 13:42   29/01/2012 6:39
 170    DEF     620026.00     7/02/2012 14:01   29/01/2012 6:39
```

Comment: row 145 is compared with row 100, since it has the latest currrentTime for the same starttime and same Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
;WITH PartData AS 
(     
    SELECT
        RowNum, Name, ItemValue, CurrentTime, StartTime,
        RX = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,StartTime ORDER BY CurrentTime DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT     
    p1.RowNum, p1.ItemValue, p1.CurrentTime, p1.StartTime, 
    RowNumComparedTo = p2.RowNum, 
    ItemActual = CASE 
                    WHEN p2.RX IS NULL THEN p1.ItemValue
                    ELSE p1.ItemValue - p2.ItemValue
                 END
FROM PartData p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PartData p2 ON p1.StartTime = p2.StartTime 
                               AND p1.Name = p2.Name 
                               AND p2.RX = p1.RX + 1
```

I get an output something like this:

```
RowNum  ItemValue   CurrentTime       StartTime        RowNumComparedTo  ItemActual
 190     664031.00  2012-02-13 13:42  2012-01-29 06:39    145            131008.00
 145     533023.00  2012-02-07 14:01  2012-01-29 06:39    100              1000.00
 100     532023.00  2012-02-07 13:33  2012-01-29 06:39     55                 0.00
  55     532023.00  2012-02-07 12:52  2012-01-29 06:39     10                 0.00
  10     532023.00  2012-02-07 12:51  2012-01-29 06:39    NULL           532023.00
 215     785034.00  2012-02-13 13:42  2012-01-29 06:39    170            165008.00
 170     620026.00  2012-02-07 14:01  2012-01-29 06:39    NULL           620026.00
 235    1086054.00  2012-05-03 14:05  2012-03-07 21:18    NULL          1086054.00
 261    1339066.00  2012-03-26 14:05  2012-03-07 21:18    NULL          1339066.00
 283     347013.00  2012-05-03 16:01  2012-04-29 06:29    NULL           347013.00
 310     351012.00  2012-05-03 16:01  2012-04-29 06:29    NULL           351012.00
```

The solution basically does this:

- it creates a CTE (Common Table Expression) and "partitions" your data by `Name,StartTime` and orders these rows by `CurrentTime DESC` - so the most recent entry for each `Name,StartTime` group will get an RX (Row indeX) of 1
- it then joins that CTE against itself, shifted by one RX - so I'm comparing RX = 1 to RX = 2 (if present) etc.
- if a "shifted" row is present, the difference in the `ItemValue` values is returned as `ItemActual` - otherwise the `ItemValue` from the main row is returned

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: sorry I did not know I had to do it.. did it now